# Google Distance API Without SSL

Tags: google-maps

Looking at the Google Distance API documentation, it says with SSL to use:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/outputFormat?parameters

and without SSL to use

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/outputFormat?parameters

but the latter crashes with an error that SSL is required. I do not see any difference between the two examples other than https vs. http and do not have or need SSL for simple distances. How is it done without it?

Currently my site is using:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/outputFormat?parameters

but it is starting to fail more and more often so I got a Google API key to try to do it officially. This does not give the SSL error but more often than not it also gives no results.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you add an API key in Distance Matrix request it enforces the HTTPS connection. I believe it makes sense, because the request will be sent in encrypted form and your API key won't be exposed. So it adds certain level of security.

I can see that HTTP connection in Distance Matrix is still possible for keyless requests. However, after June 11 and migration to Google Maps Platform the keyless access will be deprecated.

> Beginning June 11, you’ll need a valid API key and a Google Cloud Platform billing account to access our core products.

source: https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html

That means after June 11, 2018 Distance Matrix API will work only over SSL. It's time to ask Google update their documentation. Feel free to file a documentation bug in Google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188832&template=787712).

I hope my answer clarifies your doubts!

Comment: Thank you. I meant to rewrite my question as it was really dumb when I look back at it. The SSL in question, I was thinking, needed to be on my own server but after I posted I realized it was referring to the Google https which is not a problem as it means simply changing the link. However,  I have a key but can’t seem to get it configured to work in spite reading everything here and elsewhere that I can find. The connection is always refused but still trying.

Comment: Google has recently updated their root certificates. If you experience any issue with establishing SSL connection to their servers have a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67842936.

Comment: It finally connects once I set the needed APIs in the ControlPanel, which were vague so needed some guesswork to get it functional. Now that it’s working, it’s giving no results but I started another thread for that issue. Thank you.